# React hooks context doesn't update component on page until I change theme

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I'm working on a voice chat project which also contains a chat room. I have a list of members that contains some test members and I'm passing it through a context called MembersInfoContext.

Here is my App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import HeaderComponent from "./components/Header/HeaderComponent";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import VoiceRoom from "./components/main/VoiceRoom/VoiceRoom";
import ChatRoom from "./components/main/ChatRoom/ChatRoom";
import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import DropDownComponent from "./components/Header/DropDownComponent";
import { list } from "./components/Data/RawData/Members";
import { MembersInfoContext, ThemeContext } from "./Context";

function App() {
  const [memberList, setMemberList] = useState(list);

  const value = { memberList, setMemberList };

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark");

  const themeApplier = (theme) => {
    if (theme === "dark") {
      return "dark";
    } else if (theme === "light") {
      return "light";
    } else if (theme === "primary") {
      return "primary";
    }
  };

  const mainClassName = "global-font bg-" + themeApplier(theme) + " p-4";

  return (
    <MembersInfoContext.Provider value={value}>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
        <div className={mainClassName}>
          <DropDownComponent
            buttonName={theme === "dark" ? "Dark" : "Light"}
            dropDownItems={[
              {
                name: "Dark",
                action: () => {
                  setTheme("dark");
                },
              },
              {
                name: "Light",
                action: () => {
                  setTheme("light");
                },
              },
              ,
            ]}
          />
          <HeaderComponent title={"DBY voice chat app"} />
          <Row>
            <Col md={6} lg={4} xl={4} xxl={4}>
              <VoiceRoom />
            </Col>
            <Col md={6} lg={8} xl={8} xxl={8}>
              <ChatRoom />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </MembersInfoContext.Provider>

    // <Login />
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is list of my contexts:

Context.js:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import { list } from "./components/Data/RawData/Members";

export const MembersInfoContext = createContext({
  memberList: list,
  setMemberList: () => {},
});

export const ThemeContext = createContext("Default value");
```

Members.js:

```
export const list = [
  {
    profilePicture: "",
    username: "hamed",
    tag: "1510",
    chats: [
      { text: "Hello my name is hamed", date: "11:30 PM" },
      { text: "Hello my name is hamed", date: "12:30 AM" },
    ],
  },
  {
    profilePicture: "",
    username: "Doctor.B.y",
    tag: "1511",
    chats: [
      { text: "Hello my name is Doctor.B.y", date: "11:30 PM" },
      { text: "Hello my name is Doctor.B.y", date: "12:30 AM" },
    ],
  },
  {
    profilePicture: "",
    username: "Hadesius",
    tag: "1512",
    chats: [
      { text: "Hello my name is Hadesius", date: "11:30 PM" },
      { text: "Hello my name is Hadesius", date: "12:30 AM" },
    ],
  },

  {
    profilePicture: "",
    username: "Arya",
    tag: "1513",
    chats: [
      { text: "Hello my name is Arya", date: "11:30 PM" },
      { text: "Hello my name is Arya", date: "12:30 AM" },
    ],
  },
  {
    profilePicture: "",
    username: "Hezzam",
    tag: "1514",
    chats: [
      { text: "Hello my name is Hezzam", date: "11:30 PM" },
      { text: "Hello my name is Hezzam", date: "12:30 AM" },
    ],
  },
  {
    profilePicture: "",
    username: "Ali",
    tag: "1515",
    chats: [
      { text: "Hello my name is Ali", date: "11:30 PM" },
      { text: "Hello my name is Ali", date: "12:30 AM" },
    ]
  }
];
```

There is a FooterComponent.js that contains submit button and input field for typing messages:

FooterComponent.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Container, FormControl, FormGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { MembersInfoContext, ThemeContext } from "../../../Context";

export default function FooterComponent() {
  const value = useContext(MembersInfoContext);

  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const [formText, setFormText] = useState("");

  const themeApplier = (theme) => {
    if (theme === "dark") {
      return "light";
    } else if (theme === "light") {
      return "dark";
    } else if (theme === "primary") {
      return "primary";
    }
  };

  const textApplier = (theme) => {
    if (themeApplier(theme) === "light") {
      return "dark";
    } else {
      return "light";
    }
  };

  const formClassName = " d-flex flex-row m-3 p-3 ";

  const formControlClassName =
    "bg-" +
    textApplier(theme) +
    " d-flex flex-row border border-5 me-2 p-3 rounded-5 text-" +
    themeApplier(theme) +
    "";

  const submitButtonClassName =
    "header-btn btn-" +
    textApplier(theme) +
    " border border-5 ms-3 p-3 rounded-5 text-" +
    themeApplier(theme) +
    " text-center";

  const onClick = () => {
    const newMemberList = value.memberList;

    newMemberList.push({
      profilePicture: "",
      username: "Hassan",
      tag: "1515",
      chats: [
        { text: formText, date: "11:30 PM" },
        { text: "Hello my name is Ali", date: "12:30 AM" },
      ],
    });

    value.setMemberList(newMemberList);

    console.log(value.memberList);
  };

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setFormText(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <FormGroup className={formClassName}>
        <FormControl className={formControlClassName} onChange={onChange} />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          className={submitButtonClassName}
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Whenever onClick function is called, the memberList is getting updated but my components won't get updated until I change the theme of the page which belongs to another context called ThemeContext.پ

And this is the list of members chat in a component that I want to show:

ChatProfileListComponent.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { MembersInfoContext } from "../../../Context";
import ChatProfileComponent from "./ChatProfileComponent";

export default function ChatProfileListComponent() {
  const value = useContext(MembersInfoContext);

  const mainClassName =
    "d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-start";

  const listComponents = value.memberList.map((item) => (
    <ChatProfileComponent chats={item.chats} username={item.username} />
  ));

  return <div className={mainClassName}>{listComponents}</div>;
}
```

I tried using useEffect, passing member list through both props and context to some components. but my ChatProfileListComponent.js still needs refresh (or changing theme) to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in FooterComponent.js

change the onClick like this, should work

```
const onClick = () => {
    const newMemberList = [...value.memberList, {
         profilePicture: "",
         username: "Hassan",
         tag: "1515",
         chats: [
             { text: formText, date: "11:30 PM" },
             { text: "Hello my name is Ali", date: "12:30 AM" },
         ],
    }];

    value.setMemberList(newMemberList);
};
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Can you please explain to me why it didn't work before?

Comment: const newMemberList = value.memberList; - not created new array, but clones a reference to context state. so, then you mutate it and setting state with a setter. react compares the previous state with the updated state to decide if the component needs to be re-rendered. and your modifying the state directly will disturb this process. that's why it doesn't work.